# How Citing Sources in Website Content affects Google Rankings

Tags: google, duplicate-content

I am planning to scour various press releases from the web (particularly from science companies) and directly copy the material into my website. According to many of these companies, the press release can be directly used in our websites but you must include a source link at the bottom of the content. I suspect that many webmasters would be doing the same and hence there is a chance for Duplicate content. What do you suggest?

Comment: What value is your site adding to this content?

Comment: My readers will stay updated because they need not have to go to multiple sites for news!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be duplicate content for sure, with or without the link, and filtered out by Google so the value of these links are irrelevant. If you're going to do this I would block all of the press releases you post from Google so your site doesn't look like it contains a lot of duplicate content and risks being flagged by the Panda algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

The SEO effect of the link could be negated to some extent using rel="nofollow" (arguable). The best way to use the press release content is to give it a cursory rewrite. Keeping the same paragraph structure, topic order and facts but putting the text into your own wording. This will show as new content to google and thus gain your some influence. The extra effort involved in doing this is worthwhile.

Comment: The nofollow attribute is more for when it comes to PageRank and giving a bump to sites you might source for content. Typically the area it comes into play is for keeping spam links from user posts as counting as backlinks.
In terms of duplicates Google matches cached content against everything being indexed.